# How to reduce PCL file size when we use gs command to convert ps to pcl file

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, printer-control-language

I am converting a PDF file to a PS file using ghostscript.Size of PS file is normal but when I convert PS file to PCL file then size becomes very large.
I have tried many options with gs command to optimize the size but somehow did not succeed.
Can someone give me any hint on what should I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THe PCL driver basically renders the input to an image, then wraps that up with enough PCL to make it print. Your only real option to making it smaller is to reduce the resolution (if you are running at 600 dpi, then you can go to 300, PCL only supports 300 or 600 dpi)